# Remove last instance of string from an element's text

Tags: jquery, dom

I am trying to to cut the last `CHF` text out of the div. I couldn't get this to work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myval = $(".gui-big.guy-price strong").text();
  console.log(myval);
  myval = myval.substring(0, myval.length - 3);
  $("div.gui-big.guy-price strong").val(myval);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gui-item gui-big">
  <div class="gui-desc">
    <strong>Gesamt inkl. MwSt:</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="gui-price">
    <strong>CHF53,70 CHF</strong>
  </div>
```

Comment: _"I dont get this to work"_ - And what exactly does not work? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that your selectors are incorrect. It has a typo, and requires spaces to indicate that you're looking for child elements.

To replace the last occurence of one string within another you can use a regular expression. To make this more succinct you can provide a function to `text()` which accepts the current value as an argument and returns the new value to be set. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.gui-big .gui-price strong').text((i, t) => t.replace(/CHF([^CHF]*)$/, '$1'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gui-item gui-big">
  <div class="gui-desc">
    <strong>Gesamt inkl. MwSt:</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="gui-price">
    <strong>CHF53,70 CHF</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```